# Jax-WS handler for Undertow web server?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, undertow

Similar to Resteasy (Jax-rs implementation) which has an Undertow plugin and can be used in ways as described here: https://github.com/vdevigere/undertow-cdi-jaxrs/wiki/Deploying-JAX-RS-Resources-and-Applications-to-Undertow, is there an equivalent Jax-WS implementation/plugin/handler for Undertow? I've looked up online but haven't found anything.

Any suggestions/pointers appreciated! Thank you in advance.